# Rails 3 autoload_paths versus Rails 2 load_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So, I figured out that I needed to change my `config.load_paths` to `config.autoload_paths` but when I did that, I start seeing this exception:

```
Expected /path/to/myapp/app/helpers/controllers/my_helper.rb to define Controllers::MyHelper
```

In Rails 2, it never complained about the helpers/controllers folder, but now it seems that it expects a namespaced module. Do I have rename all of my helpers, or is there some other way this can work? I have so many helpers that I use helpers/models helpers/views and helpers/controllers to keep them all organized.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when I renamed them to `Controllers::MyHelper` it complained that it was expecting `MyHelper` lol. Is there any way to organize helpers in Rails 3?

Comment: What kind of helpers are you using in your controllers? Normally helpers are for the views. If you need shared functionality for controllers you either include it in your ApplicationController so that your controllers inherit it or you store it in a module or something in lib/ and include it.

Answer (score 0):

File naming conventions in Rails 3 are a lot more strict than they were in Rails 2 for performance reasons. Rails 3 expects the file structure to directly match the class hierarchy.

If you would like the run the application in Rails 3 I would suggest removing the helpers directory or adding `Controllers::` to the front of each class declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect, it is actually a Rails 3 thing.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 does expect your classes to be namespaced according to file name and directory hierarchy, so you will have to rename your helper to `Controllers::MyHelper`.